# Custom sort in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following set and I would like to bring the parties whose statuses are `FORSALE` at first, `OPENED` at second and `CLOSED` at last.
The parties which are `FORSALE` or `OPENED` must be ordered from the newest to the oldest ones. The parties which are `CLOSED` must be ordered from the oldest to the newest ones (`start_time` field).

Any clue how could I build a query using MongoDB?

```
{
    "id": "608",
    "facebook_event_id": "840660989387123",
    "title": "Direito Ã  Fantasia - Save The Date",
    "hot": false,
    "admission": null,
    "local": "Prime Hall",
    "start_time": "2015-11-13T23:11:00-0500",
    "college": {
    "name": "PontifÃ­cia Universidade CatÃ³lica De Campinas",
    "initials": "PUCCAMP"
},
    "status": "FORSALE",
    "fee": "10",
    "attending": {
    "men": null,
    "women": null,
    "total": null,
    "media": null
},
    "images": {
        "cover": "cover608.gif",
        "detail": "detail608.gif"
    }
 },
{
    "id": "600",
    "facebook_event_id": "925972197477371",
    "title": "Cam Rodeo Festival 2015",
    "hot": false,
    "admission": null,
    "local": "Barroca Zona Sul",
    "start_time": "2015-11-13T22:11:00-0500",
    "college": {
        "name": "Universidade De SÃ£o Paulo",
        "initials": "USP"
    },
    "status": "OPENED",
    "fee": "10",
    "attending": {
        "men": null,
        "women": null,
        "total": null,
        "media": null
    },
    "images": {
        "cover": "cover600.gif",
        "detail": "detail600.gif"
    }
},
{
    "id": "588",
    "facebook_event_id": "1651374941773874",
    "title": "SabÃ³ia 2 ",
    "hot": false,
    "admission": null,
    "local": "EspaÃ§o Anchieta.",
    "start_time": "2015-11-07T23:11:00-0500",
    "college": {
        "name": "Faculdade De Engenharia Industrial",
        "initials": "FEI"
    },
    "status": "OPENED",
    "fee": "10",
    "attending": {
        "men": null,
        "women": null,
        "total": null,
        "media": null
    },
    "images": {
        "cover": "cover588.gif",
        "detail": "detail588.gif"
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a problem with the dates since they are strings. You have perhaps done this deliberately to keep the timezone information, but it is a very wrong approach. You should convert these to BSON dates as UTC, and then it is possible. With some trickery, but possible.